# Two AutomaticMigration records in the __MigrationHistory table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In the **__MigrationHistory** table  after my last migration i have two **AutomaticMigration** records. Why it could happen?

Problem is, I lost data from the table I created during last migration. It feels like table was deleted and created again.

All my **DbMigration** have **Down()** method

```
AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
```

[image]

Comment: Dou you use source control?

Comment: @GuruStron, yes. Some time ago migrate from SVN to Git

Comment: Have you checked if there were any changes to the EF related stuff in the time between migrations?